# Zeros of order $m$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

Suppose that $f$ has a root $\alpha$ of order $m$. Prove that $\alpha$ is a root of order $2m-1$ for 
$$
\theta(x)=f(x+f(x))-f(x).
$$
My attempt:
We can take $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^{m}q(x)$ where $q(\alpha)\neq0$. However, I can not see the result from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the linear Taylor polynomial with the quadratic remainder term one gets
\begin{align}
f(x+f(x))-f(x)&=f'(x)f(x)+\frac12f''(x+θf(x))f(x)^2
\end{align}
where the first term has root multiplicity $2m-1$ and the second $2m$, so that the sum has multiplicity $2m-1$.

Comment: Presumably your use of $\theta$ in the "quadratic" term is related to the evaluation of the "remainder" second derivative at a point between $x$ and $x+f(x)$, but is it consistent with the use of $\theta$ in the Question?

Comment: No, not the $θ(x)$ in the question, just the traditional convention for the parameter for the midpoint in the remainder term.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= (x-\alpha)^{m}g(x) \\
  f'(x) &= m(x-\alpha)^{m-1}g(x)+(x-\alpha)^{m}g'(x) \\
  f(x+f(x)) &= f(x+(x-\alpha)^{m}g(x)) \\
  &= f(x)+(x-\alpha)^{m}g(x)f'(x)+\ldots \\
  f(x+f(x))-f(x) &= (x-\alpha)^{m} g(x) f'(x)+\ldots \\
  &= m(x-\alpha)^{2m-1} g(x)+\ldots
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you write the 4th equality?

Comment: Taylor series expansion $f(x+h(x))=f(x)+h(x)f'(x)+[h(x)]^{2} \frac{f''(x)}{2}+\ldots$, then replace $h(x)$ by $f(x)$.